# gzserver: error while loading shared libraries: libdart-collision-bullet.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: gazebo-11, ubuntu-20.04

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I don't even know how did this happen. One day, I just open the laptop and start to work. Suddenly, it's not working anymore.

I can't even run turtlebot3. I reinstalled foxy and gazebo11. No luck. It just...out of blue not working again.

killall gzserver/killall gzclient/ pkill doesn't help at all. ANy idea? I really want to use gazebo again

error

```
gzserver: error while loading shared libraries: libdart-collision-bullet.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

even i reinstall gazebo11, this happens still.

```
bwuk@robots:~$ cd /usr/local/bin/gazebo
bash: cd: /usr/local/bin/gazebo: No such file or directory
bwuk@robots:~$
```

I still have .model though

```
bwuk@robots:~$ cd .gazebo/models/
bwuk@robots:~/.gazebo/models$
```

Everytime I load gazebo from launch, it simply frozen, crashed or says directory doesn't exist.

How did this happen?

I even echo path, but it just don't show any result

```
bwuk@robots:~$ echo $GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH

bwuk@robots:~$ echo $GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH

bwuk@robots:~$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27311/gzserver:-error-while-loading-shared-libraries:-libdart-collision-bullet.so.6:-cannot-open-shared-object-file:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 87 on 2021-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Solution:

```
sudo apt remove --purge libdart*
Remove dartsim/ppa in Software & Updates -> Other Software
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libdart-dev
sudo apt install libdart-all-dev (only if above installs)
```

But if this failed due to unable to fetch some archives, run this

```
    sudo apt update --fix-missing && sudo apt install libdart-all-dev
    

    Install gazebo curl -sSL http://get.gazebosim.org | sh
```

Finally,

Type `gazebo` (to check if it works now)

If you still getting error after attempt to load gazebo from launch in ros2, then follow this;

`. /usr/share/gazebo/setup.sh` inside your workspace.

Source:

```
ROS answer: [link](https://answers.ros.org/question/385317/gzserver-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libdart-collision-bulletso6-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory/)

rajputusername on stackoverflow on Gazebo 11 does not run question page
```

---

Originally posted by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) with karma: 87 on 2021-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1